# Inheritance with Jackson by specific json key name

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have this json:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {"expression": "count(*)"},
    {"column": "field1"},
  ]
}
```

I want use inheritance. I created classes:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Expression.class, name = "expression"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Field.class, name = "column")})
public abstract class TargetClause {
}
```

Expression:

```
public class Expression extends TargetClause {

    @JsonProperty("expression", required = true)
    String expression;
}
```

Field:

```
public class Field extends TargetClause {

    @JsonProperty(value = "column", required = true)
    String column;
}
```

And wrapper object:
public class Wrapper {

```
@JsonProperty(value = "fields", required = true)
List<TargetClause> fields;
```

}

But, It don't work for me. I get error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class TargetClause]: missing type id property '@type' (for POJO property 'fields')
```

But, I don't want add any field im my json. I want jackson to understand what type of object this object belongs to by using the key name in json. If it is `expression` => `Expression` class, if `column` => `Field` class. How can this be done?

Comment: The structure of the json is very confusing, not a good practice to put different structure/type in an array, it will make your code more complex. Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve from the json, but I am sure you can make it more structured and also make the ser/deser easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the options will be to use custom deserializer based on the property expression or column.

Please check https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1627

Comment: Tnx. This code: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1627#issuecomment-384190255 work for me